# Set value of variable to return value of expression

Tags: java

So i am trying to set the value of a variable to the return value of an expression like lambda, Runnable or Callable. Is there any way of doing this in java?

i tried doing something like this:

```
int number = () -> {
   return 1;
};
```

but it just shows me a syntax error in Intellij

Comment: Maybe set the return type to `Supplier<Integer>` or something instead of `int`? See: [Package java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) for more types of interfaces.

Comment: In other words, you're assigning the number variable to a function here, so the return statement isn't being ran at all, therefore the type cannot be int

Answer (score 2):

The lambda needs an explicit type in this context. You could cast it to [`IntSupplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntSupplier.html) and call its `getAsInt` method to get the return value.

```java
int number = ((IntSupplier) () -> 1).getAsInt();
```